# Getting rid of duplicate values in my query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that very simply looks like this:

```
SELECT
event_time,
service_id,
order_id,
total_value,
purchase_type
FROM
order.table
```

Again, it's a very simple query. The problem is, it produces some results like this:

```
event_time     service_id   order_id   total_value purchase_type
8/19/18 16:18   305030       42549440   39.98       PVC 
8/19/18 16:09   305030       42549440   39.98       PCC
```

The problem is in the duplicate `order_id` numbers. What if I wanted to write a query that simply takes the earlieer `order_id` and gets rid of the later version? For the record, I tried doing this `MIN(event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) conversion_time` but it didn't do the trick. Is there a different function I should be using?

Comment: The questions was closed as "duplicate" - but the answer to this question is not the same as the designated one. The answer given there was `GROUP BY`, but what the person asking this question needs is to go beyond `GROUP BY` and choose one of the full rows (earliest) that might not be the exact duplicate, other than the id.

Answer (score 4):

One method uses window functions, something like:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*, row_number() over (partition by order_id order by event_time) as seqnum
      from order.table o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

Although this is the "typical" method, another method uses fewer resources:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*, min(event_time) over (partition by order_id) as min_event_time 
     from order.table o
     ) o
where min_event_time = event_time;
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT row.*
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY event_time LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] row
  FROM `order.table` t
  GROUP BY order_id
)
```